# the unusual error I meet in the virtualenv install

Tags: python, virtualenv, osx-mavericks, homebrew, gevent

I try to install some requirement lib in a new virtualenv directory when I use the the `pip install -r requirement.txt` commmand. I got this error:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): wsgiref==0.1.2 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7 (from -r requirement.txt (line 19))
Installing collected packages: greenlet, grequests, killproc, kombu, mccabe, pep8, psutil, pyflakes, pytz, redis, requests
  Running setup.py install for greenlet
    cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -pipe -fno-tree-dominator-opts -arch x86_64 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c /var/folders/5h/63q1xmj961b7hv9y0ntdt7gc0000gn/T/tmpXfAIrt/simple.c -o /var/folders/5h/63q1xmj961b7hv9y0ntdt7gc0000gn/T/tmpXfAIrt/var/folders/5h/63q1xmj961b7hv9y0ntdt7gc0000gn/T/tmpXfAIrt/simple.o
    clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
    clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
    clang: error: unknown argument: '-fno-tree-dominator-opts' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
    clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
    building 'greenlet' extension
    cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -pipe -arch x86_64 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c greenlet.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/greenlet.o
    clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
    clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /Users/penkzhou/.virtualenvs/JOB_ENV/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/Users/penkzhou/.virtualenvs/JOB_ENV/build/greenlet/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/5h/63q1xmj961b7hv9y0ntdt7gc0000gn/T/pip-FNK0mO-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/penkzhou/.virtualenvs/JOB_ENV/include/site/python2.7:
    running install

running build

running build_ext

creating /var/folders/5h/63q1xmj961b7hv9y0ntdt7gc0000gn/T/tmpXfAIrt/var

creating /var/folders/5h/63q1xmj961b7hv9y0ntdt7gc0000gn/T/tmpXfAIrt/var/folders

creating /var/folders/5h/63q1xmj961b7hv9y0ntdt7gc0000gn/T/tmpXfAIrt/var/folders/5h

creating /var/folders/5h/63q1xmj961b7hv9y0ntdt7gc0000gn/T/tmpXfAIrt/var/folders/5h/63q1xmj961b7hv9y0ntdt7gc0000gn

creating /var/folders/5h/63q1xmj961b7hv9y0ntdt7gc0000gn/T/tmpXfAIrt/var/folders/5h/63q1xmj961b7hv9y0ntdt7gc0000gn/T

creating /var/folders/5h/63q1xmj961b7hv9y0ntdt7gc0000gn/T/tmpXfAIrt/var/folders/5h/63q1xmj961b7hv9y0ntdt7gc0000gn/T/tmpXfAIrt

cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -pipe -fno-tree-dominator-opts -arch x86_64 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c /var/folders/5h/63q1xmj961b7hv9y0ntdt7gc0000gn/T/tmpXfAIrt/simple.c -o /var/folders/5h/63q1xmj961b7hv9y0ntdt7gc0000gn/T/tmpXfAIrt/var/folders/5h/63q1xmj961b7hv9y0ntdt7gc0000gn/T/tmpXfAIrt/simple.o

clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

clang: error: unknown argument: '-fno-tree-dominator-opts' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

building 'greenlet' extension

creating build

creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -pipe -arch x86_64 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c greenlet.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/greenlet.o

clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

I have installed the `brew` and the Python environment is installed by this [instruction](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/).Another information is that I have install some python lib with mac's origin python environment on an old mac account.Then I want to start from scratch and switch to a new mac account.Then I got the above error when I install some lib in the virtualenv environment. I Google `-mno-fused-madd` but I got nothing.So any body know something about that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.I find a solution [here](http://www.blueleftistconstructor.com/2011/12/19/install-gevent-greenlets-on-os-x/). Maybe I lose some detail when I install `gevent`.So I need install libevent first:

```
brew install libevent
```

Then I must set this flag so that gevent can build:

```
export CFLAGS=-I/opt/local/include
```

After that,I can install `gevent` successfully in the virtualenv. May this help you guys.